# Good NFS configuration for Home Network (NFS Performance Issues)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, nfs

I have a small LAN that has a couple of Linux boxes (Ubuntu 9.10) with NFS shares on them. The boxes are networked with a consumer grade Netgear router (model WGR614V9) and using wired connections.

When I first set up the NFS shares, I noticed that performance was pretty terrible. For example, it would take a few minutes to copy 40 mbs worth data from a mounted NFS share to local disk.

By playing around with the NFS configuration, I was able to get things running reasonably well. The configuration I settled on for the system exporting the share was:

```
# /etc/exports On the machine exporting the NFS share:
/exprt/dir client.ip (rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

For the NFS client, I have

```
# /etc/fstab
server.ip:/exprt/dir on /imprt/dir type nfs (rw,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=14,intr)
```

However, while this seems to work reasonably well for me, it still seems to be faster to copy files from one system to the other using `scp` than it is using NFS.

I thought it would be worth asking what NFS configurations other people might be using on similar network set ups that results in reasonably good performance. I know NFS can be pretty sensitive to things like choice of OS and precise network configuration. But, I suspect the set up I have is pretty common amount other users with small local networks, so it would be useful to hear what configuration works best for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS should easily outperform SSHFS.  Can you show some specific numbers?

if you run on your server..

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.a bs=1M count=100
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.b bs=1M count=100
```

then can you do

```
dd if=/imprt/dir/test.a of=/dev/null
dd if=/path/to/sshfs/mount/dir/test.b of=/dev/null
```

and post the output?

also, you might want to export the shares under /export and use autofs with auto.net on the clients. which makes all the machines on the lan use the same /net/$hostname/export/foo path structure.

Comment: I was just looking at scp performance vs. NFS, not SSHFS vs. NFS. But, thanks for the pointer to SSHFS. SSHFS looks useful for mounting boxes remotely.

Comment: oh, my bad.. the performance of sshfs should match what you see with scp anyway :-)

Comment: Interesting, with the current configuration, NFS is about equal to SSHFS. 

NFS:

dd if=NFSmnt/test.a of=/dev/null
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 8.95725 s, 11.7 MB/s

SSFS:

dd if=SSHFSmnt/test.b of=/dev/null
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 9.14158 s, 11.5 MB/s

Comment: Interesting indeed.  Can you come up with a repeatable test that reproduces the problem you first described?

Comment: I suspect not, since scp is about as fast as SSHFS (~9 s). But, shouldn't NFS be faster than SSHFS, since it doesn't have to do the additional work of encrypting the data being sent over the network?

Comment: in the numbers you showed NFS was faster, though it was only by .2 seconds.  The rates you are getting indicate you are maxing out a 100mbit link, so your bottle neck is that, and not NFS or SSH.

Comment: I found tuning NFS either preferred lots of small files or a few large files with buffering disabled. Attempting both at once created a lot of contention. I also went to bonded Gig-E connections and had a lot of spindles on my nfs server.